# Black screen after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia

I have laptop with mobile 1050ti.
I installed nvidia-435 via standart driver manager and it works correct I think.
nvidia-smi shows info, nvidia-prime seted to tonvidia.
After reboot I got black screen, rebooted to cli
Blacklisted nouveau, but there is still black screen.
How shoud i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I tried to boot with nomodset, no result

Comment: recommendationsto reinstall the driver, but shoud i do it? It seems to work ok

Comment: Yeah, i have already nomodeset in grub boot config, i replaced quiet splash with no splash and nomodeset, but my screen is still black

Comment: Im not sure I need to reinstall the driver. After installing im loadet to kde and it was ok. I got a problem after trying prime-switch to nvidia